# NSPredicate key inside NSManagedObject class relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I have an `NSArray` of this `NSManagedObject` class lets call it People, inside there is a relationship to-one for another `NSManagedObject` class let call it Car, I want to predicate an `NSArray` of the first class which will get me an ID of a car. I'm doing it like this:

```
DbCar *c = [self.cars firstObject];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"car.idNum == %@", c.idNum.stringValue];
NSArray *sorted = [self.mainData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
self.sortedData = sorted;
```

`self.mainData` is an `NSArray` that hold 'People' `NSManagedObject`

For some reason I always get nil.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your predicate is trying to match an attribute named `car` on instances of `DbCar`. That *seems* like it might not be correct but it's impossible to be sure. Does `DbCar` have a `car` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NSNumber` type of properties don't need to pass `stringValue` property of that number. Directly pass that number object itself as an argument to the predicate as follows:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"car.idNum == %@", c.idNum];
```

This will help!

Comment: I just figure out that I don't need to send `stringValue` of `NSNumber`, I can send the `NSNumber` itself or it's `integerValue`.

Comment: Yes, You have to send only ` NSNumber` there as argument.